# Insert BBCode into CKEditor's in parsed form

Tags: javascript, parsing, insert, ckeditor, bbcode

Let's say I have a button on a webpage that when pressed, inserts specific $text formatted with BBCode into CKEditor. It's easy to make the $text be inserted in unparsed form with this line:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.message.insertText(text);
```

But how can I make the $text be inserted in already parsed form? .insertHtml pastes in same form as insertText.I do know its for Html but couldn't find any other insert function, so I tried this one.

```
CKEDITOR.instances.message.insertHtml(text);
```

What is the name of the function that pastes the thing with preparsing? When you do CTRL+C and CTRL+V, you paste the parsed form.

Anyone got ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one:

```
var writer = new CKEDITOR.htmlWriter();
CKEDITOR.htmlParser.fragment.fromBBCode( '[b]Bold[/b]' ).writeHtml( writer );
CKEDITOR.instances.message.insertHtml( writer.getHtml() );
```

It uses [fromBBCode](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.htmlParser.fragment-static-method-fromBBCode) method to convert BBCode into htmlParser's fragment.

Comment: Thanks @oleq , it works but partially. It only parses tag alone like [quote] and ignores it's properties and values like in this: [quote="Vioner" pid="3676" dateline="1456144839"]. I wonder how to make this possible hmm.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to @oleq CKEditor documentation and source code of a custom made js found somewhere I've found a solution.

@oleq solution only works for parsing tags without additional properties. 
so `[quote] [url]` etc. not `[quote="something"] [url="http://]`

This one line should parse and insert all content from var text:

```
clickableEditor.Insert(text, bbcodeParser.bbcodeToHtml(text));
```

Found this in custom files from plugin MyBB CKEditor. Based on code:

```
MyBBEditor = {
    insertText: function(a)
    {
        if(clickableEditor.editor.mode == 'wysiwyg')
        {
            clickableEditor.Insert(a, bbcodeParser.bbcodeToHtml(a));
        }
        else
        {
            clickableEditor.performInsert(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Users that have CKEditor plugin on their MyBB forum can also use:

```
MyBBEditor.insertText(your_variable);
```

Let me know if this has some flaws or something I forgot about - like exceptions?